# What to call a typographical error that is literally typographical?

Tags: terminology

"Typographical error", or more briefly, "typo", is often used for spelling errors, accidentally missing or added words, etc.  Sometimes, though, there is an error that is precisely an error only in the typeface or font used.  In mathematical contexts the style of a letter can convey meaning, and this sort of mistake can be quite significant.  (For example, one convention is to use normal-weight math italic characters as variables that represent single numbers, and boldface math italic characters for variables that represent vectors, which are sequences of numbers.)

What term or brief phrase would you suggest to convey that the error is strictly with the style of a printed letter?  I don't want to write "typographical error" and then explain that I don't mean this in the usual sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the below would indicate to me that the *actual* content/text **is** correct and the error exists in *how* it is formatted.

1. Typeface Error / inconsistency 
   (Indicates incorrect typeface/face is
   used.)
2. Typesetting Error / inconsistency 
   (Indicates incorrect style, i.e. should be set super/sub script, bold, italic, et al.)
3. **Typestyle/Style** error / inconsistency
   (Same as #2 but more general, could mean color, size, etc. as well. In my world, this is the clearest and most encompassing, causing an examination of the marked content for *any* inconsistency.)
4. Font error / inconsistency
   (Basically same as #1 - incorrect typeface is used.)
5. Formatting error / inconsistency
    (Often used to indicate
   incorrect spacing, alignment, or type size more than anything else. But, in reality, using "spacing/alignment/size error" would be much more succinct.)

I tend to lean more towards using "inconsistency" rather than "error" in such cases. It designates, at least to me, that there's a *visual* anomaly as opposed to an input error.

Comment: Thanks--these are good suggestions.  I like "inconsistency", even though I think "error" is correct in the case I have in mind.  It's clear that the typeface inconsistency was probably the result of a *typo* in the author's or typesetter's source file. :-)

Comment: Whether you use error or inconsistency isn't *that* imperative. They are relatively interchangeable.